# mysql total of goals scored by team A

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find the total scored and conceeded by Team A over the last 6 matches (total) whether TeamA is the home or away team.
For example: we'll assume $teamA = 'Arsenal' and search for last 6 results,

which gives the result below:

```
Leicester City  1 - 1   Arsenal
Everton         2 - 2   Arsenal
Arsenal         2 - 1   Crystal Palace
Norwich City    0 - 2   Arsenal
Arsenal         1 - 0   West Bromwich Albion
Arsenal         3 - 0   Newcastle United
```

Above is the output of the query to get the last 6 results, now i need to get the goals total for $teamA and $teamB

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM football WHERE `HomeTeam` = '$teamA' OR AwayTeam = '$teamA' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

  if ($row['HomeTeam'] = $teamA){  
    $teamAgoals = $teamAgoals + $row['FTHG'];
  }


  if ($row2['AwayTeam'] = $teamA){  
    $teamAgoals = $teamAgoals + $row['FTAG'];
  }
  $tot++;

  if ($tot == 7):
    exit;
  endif;
}
```

The problem I have is LIMIT in the query returns the last 6 home games or last 6 away games.

Comment: can you provide the schema? also, using mysql_* functions is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and is not recommended to be used in new code.  Consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: What are the results you want?  How do you define "the last six matches"?  Is there a timestamp or something?

Comment: can you show table structure?

Comment: Hi, the table rows are id, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG  thanks I will change to mysqli. Results are ordered by id DESC.

Comment: the result i need are total scored by teamA and total scored by TeamB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to determine if the team is the home team or the away team:

```
SELECT   SUM (CASE WHEN `HomeTeam` = '$teamA' THEN fthg ELSE ftag END)
FROM     football
WHERE    '$teamA' IN (`HomeTeam`, `AwayTeam`)
ORDER BY `MatchDate` DESC -- I'm guessing there's something like this
LIMIT    6
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not limiting to 6, would a sub-query be possible with this

Answer (score 0):

@Mureinik I tried your solution and after a bit of adjustment I've got the answer I needed, thank you for your help. I began to get this error

> Every derived table must have its own alias.

I added an alias 'totals' to the query and it works perfectly.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `HomeTeam` = 'Arsenal' THEN FTHG ELSE FTAG END) AS scored, SUM(CASE WHEN `AwayTeam` = 'Watford' THEN FTHG ELSE FTAG END) AS conceeded FROM ( SELECT Hometeam,Awayteam,FTHG,FTAG FROM football WHERE 'Arsenal' IN (`HomeTeam`, `Awayteam`) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6) as totals
```